# Python convert two lines of Excel to CSV without row or column numbers

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I want to convert a `xlsx-file` to `.csv`. I tried it with this function:

```
def excel_to_csv(excel_file, csv_file):
    # read Excel file into pandas dataframe
    df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)

    # write dataframe to CSV file
    df.to_csv(csv_file, index=False, header=False)
```

This is my Excel-file:

[image]

It is always two lines.

But when running the function above it removes the first line of my Excel-file.
That happens because I set `header=False`. However if I don't set that it places random `1` in my `csv` file.

As workaround I could add an empty first line, but is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is reading the first row of the xlsx as the header and then discarding it. Instead, read the xlsx as:

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, header=None)
```

Including `header=None` assumes there is no header in the xlsx file. The default is `header=0`, which assumes the first row is the header.